# Is my example the same case as the link I gave?

Tags: american-english, past-tense, participle-clauses

Does "She went into the home and left shoes on the floor" equal "she went into the home, leaving the shoes on the floor". Plus, many people of this site said it was not the same thing. But I wish you guys could check the link below out.

Comment: http://www.grammaring.com/participle-clauses check it out. See the "an action that happens just before another action"

Comment: You may improve the original question rather than putting an extension of it as a new question.

Comment: @MaulikV I believe that what the OP is asking is 2 different questions. The first is asking of if other tenses can be used in such grammatical structure, and this one is asking of _why_ those 2 sentences are different as in response to your comment in the other question.

Comment: @CipherBot the link the user provides talks about participle clauses for which the user is confused. Here, in the question the OP asks us to check the source where his/her query comes from.  The OP can improve the original question by citing the source.